# I would like to implement custom slider with multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

```css
div.inline { 
      display: inline-block;
      float:left  width: 250px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      width: 250px;
      background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    }
```

```html
<div class="inline">
  <img src="img/1.png" alt="logo" />
  <h2>stage 1</h2>
  <h3>

  <a ng-click="function()" role="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"> Play</a>  
  </h3>
</div>
<div class="inline">
  <img src="img/1.png" alt="logo" />
  <h2>stage 1</h2>
  <h3>

  <a ng-click="function()" role="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"> Play</a>  
  </h3>
</div>
<div class="inline">
  <img src="img/1.png" alt="logo" />
  <h2>stage 1</h2>
  <h3>

  <a ng-click="function()" role="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"> Play</a>  
  </h3>
</div>
<div class="inline">
  <img src="img/1.png" alt="logo" />
  <h2>stage 1</h2>
  <h3>

  <a ng-click="function()" role="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"> Play</a>  
  </h3>
</div>
```

now i can place these divs in a line but my problem is how can i make these divs as custom slider can some one give me some hint how can i develop 
"multiple divs as slider" so far  i did like this and i think its going to help full for others also thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to make a carousel/slideshow controlled by a slider?

Comment: i am trying to make carousel @gaynorvader and why you give me negative voting for this question  i did not understand

Comment: I did not downvote your question. Here's a tutorial I found helpful when I was tying to build a carousel http://www.queness.com/post/923/create-a-simple-infinite-carousel-with-jquery

Comment: thanks @gaynorvader i am new to this enviroment

Comment: No problem, stack overflow takes a little while to get used to :)